# Remove files unrelated to WordPress from uploads

Tags: uploads, wp-cli

Is there a wp-cli command or any easy way to remove files that are unrelated to WordPress, but FTPed or synced to the uploads directory accidentally?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is a better WP-CLI way or not, but you could write a simple script that recursively crawls your uploads directory (or it's subdirectories) and than check the absolute paths (URLs) of those files and compare them against `guid` column in `wp_posts` table.

If your file is not there, WordPress doesn't know about it and it probably can be deleted.

Comment: Danger, danger. Files can not only be linked in posts. Couldn't also a widget or even a category contain a link to an unmanaged file? Probably worth crawling your site after the purge to find any 404 caused by missing files.

Comment: @leymannx I believe it doesn't metter whether the image is added to a post, to a widget or to something else. Because once the image gets upload via native WP uploader, it is stored in the database as a `post`, which is WP's default entity. It is stored in `wp_post` table with `post_type` set to `attachment` (and `post_mime_type` set to `image/png`). You don't have to crawl anything, only compare your /uploads/ folder with wp_posts table.

Comment: Ah yeah, but I meant those files that have been uploaded via FTP and just a link has been put in the post/widget/whatsoever. Unmanaged files.